# XAML "Invalid Markup" error when using EventToCommand in VS2012

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, mvvm-light, silverlight-5.0

I have recently switched to Visual Studio Premium 2012, and discovered a XAML designer issue while using MVVM Light (v. 4.0.23.4) on a Silverlight 5 project. Here is the snippet of code that triggers the issue:

```
<sdk:AutoCompleteBox Text="{Binding Path=SomeProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SomeCollectionProperty}">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyUp">                                                           
        <mvvmlight:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=SomeRelayCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SomeParameter}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

The relevant namespaces are:

```
xmlns:mvvmlight="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

This gives me an **"Invalid Markup"** error on the designer view and a **"A value of type 'EventToCommand' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'TriggerActionCollection'** error on the EventToCommand line in the xaml. This does not happen in VS2010.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anyone figured this out?  I just converted a similar project to VS2012 and have the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure you have the most up to date version of System.Windows.Interactivity?

Comment: I have the same problem with SL5 and eventToCommand doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alyce solve the problem. The problem was the system.windows.interactivity, just use nuget to update this assembly and it will works :)